# div with 100% width inside div with 90% width doesn't work

Tags: css, html, width, wrapper

I made an image slider for my forum homepage but the content is comming out of the wrapper.

How can I make sure the content will always be 100% width of the wrapper?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="rg-content">
            //image slider code
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #e7e7e7);
}

.rg-content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #101010;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: try display:block, or display:inline-block on the css... and why use tables?

Comment: Could you not use tables? http://jsfiddle.net/jzLN6/2/

Comment: The tables are standard for content in SFM forums, here's a jsfiddle with the full slider http://jsfiddle.net/bB9tQ/ (when I give the rg-content a width in px it works, but I want it to be responsive in %)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<table style="width:100%;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jzLN6/

EDIT:

according to your jsfinddle and your comments I made some modifications to get this result

http://jsfiddle.net/bB9tQ/4/embedded/result/

is not fully functional but maybe its a basic idea of what you want to do

so if you want the layout to be fluid you will have to do some changes

remove de px of your ul and change your display to inline-block because if you have

```
display: block
```

this will make your li elements to lose the normal flow on the page and you won't be able to use % to stretch the content

```
 <ul style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; margin-left: ;">
```

after that you should use % on each li  tag instead of px.

if this is an approach to what you need, please let me know to give you a better elaborated example

Comment: That don't work when there's content inside, to bad.

Comment: can you post one jsfiddle to get a better understand.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with the full slider http://jsfiddle.net/bB9tQ/ (when I give the rg-content a width in px it works, but I want it to be responsive in %)

Answer (score 0):

### What's Going On

It looks like your `#wrapper` doesn't have `overflow` set to `hidden`.  Personally I tend to stay away from `tables` and use either `float`'d `block` elements or `inline-block` elements. I recently built a slider using `figure` for the outside wrap, `ul` for the fixed width inner wrap, and `li`s for each item. I had to set the `figure` to `overflow:hidden` for it to hide everything that wasn't supposed to be visible. Try adding that.

### Code

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The tables are standard for content in SFM forums, I removed all styles from the tables so they won't affect my div's.

overflow:hidden indeed hide everything that is outside the wrapper, but I don't want it to be hidden, I want it to auto adjust it's width to fit inside the wrapper.

Comment: You said it is a slider in your question, but now you say that you want to fit everything inside the wrapper. If it all is visible in the wrapper, how does it slide?

Comment: Yes, it is a slider, but the hidden overflow hide the part of the slide thats outside the wrapper, thats not right...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. For anything to slide in and out of view, there has to be something hidden. If you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish in the question or here?